# Changing Index Page - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, indexing, blogs

I am new to rails so go easy. I have developed my blog and deployed it successfully. The entire app is based out of the post_controller. I am wondering how I can reroute the users path to default to the post_controller vs. the app controller.

To illustrate, if you go to http://mylifebattlecry.heroku.com you will see the default rails page. If you go to http://mylifebattlecry.heroku.com/posts you will see the the app. Once I complete this I will change my domain of http://www.mylifebattlecry.com to map to Heroku but need to know how to get the /posts to be where the visitor is sent.

Comment: You have a bad habit of putting "easy question" in your titles. It does nothing but clutter up a limited space. Please stop.

Comment: Oh, I thought it enticed people to answer my question because they could get points for spending only a short amount of time. Guess I was wrong, I will stop.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to do two things

1. Delete the file /public/index.html
2. Update the file /config/routes.rb

`map.root :controller => "posts"  #RAILS 2`

or

`root :to => 'posts#index'  #RAILS 3`

This will then call the index action in your posts controller.
You will need to restart the application to see changes to routes.rb

Comment: What should this be for rails 3?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your confing/routes.rb:

```
map.root :controller => "posts"
```

You need to restart your server after that.